# How can I check if string value exists in array of chars?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "cab";
    string d = "";
    char s[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(s) / sizeof(s[0]); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++){
            if(str[j] == s[i]){
                d += s[i];
            }
        }
    }
    cout << d << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I wanna check if the string "cab" for example exists in array of chars like in my case, it should exist, no matter of position in the element in the array of chars.

Comment: or just `find`? it does exactly this

Comment: It seems that you are looking for [`std::includes`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg arguably, the find method is part of the string class so may be faster, and ignores the null by default

Comment: @user3125280 `find` (from the string class) looks for substrings, which doesn't seem to be what the OP wants.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg is that not the question? ( to see if "cab" is substring of s?)

Comment: @user3125280 First the OP wants to find all of the characters in `str` exists in the array `s` (which is not a string), then the OP says that the letters `'c'`, `'a'` and `'b'` should be found in `s` no matter the positions. So `"cab"` is not a substring, it's set of distinct characters.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg fair enough - that's what the code implies, but the english says find string. i'll change my answer to have both

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your sub string will not have duplicates, you could use an [`unordered_set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/). So you essentially iterate over your `s[]` and for each character, you will check if the set contains that particular character.

The `unordered_set` allows O(1) searching, so your algorithm should run in O(n) (n = size of `s`).

When you find a character in the set which is also within the array, you remove it and continue traversing the array. If by the time your are done traversing the array the set is empty, then you know that your array contains that substring. You can also check to see that the set is not empty each time you remove a character from it, this should reduce execution time.

Answer (score 1):

Not my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void print(std::string::size_type n, std::string const &s)
{
    if (n == std::string::npos) {
        std::cout << "not found\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "found: " << s.substr(n) << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "cab";
    std::string::size_type n;
    std::string const s = "This is a string";

    // search from beginning of string
    n = s.find("is");
    print(n, s);

    // search from position 5
    n = s.find("is", 5);
    print(n, s);

    // find a single character
    n = s.find('a');
    print(n, s);

    // find a single character
    n = s.find('q');
    print(n, s);

    //not the best way
    for(char c : s)
     s.find(c); //will be npos if it doesn't exist

    //better
    std::includes( s.begin(), s.end(),
           str.begin(), str.end() );
}
```